# AngularJS: variable $scope inside a function appears undefined outside the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-scope

I am new with AngularJS and I am stuck :\ NEED HELP, please!

The purpose of the code below is to get a specific data (an integer) from a DB in order to build a doughnut chart.
I run the function dataforGraphs() in order to get that value. But then, outside the function, I "loose" that value.

(during the code, I made comments to explain better the situation)

```
uONEControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'GraphService',
function ($scope, GraphService) {


    var ammountOfFinishedOrders = {};

    dataforGraphs(); // calling the function

    function dataforGraphs() {

       GraphService.getAmmountOfFinishedOrders()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders = data.GetAmmountOfFinishedOrdersResult;
            //this console.log shows me the value 3. Excellent!
            console.log("value 1:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)

            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data:' + error.message;
            });
            //HOWEVER... here is undefined
            console.log("value 2:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)
    };

            //here, outside the function, too :(
            console.log("value 3:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)        

    //building the doughnut graphic
    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

      //THE PROBLEM IS HERE. The  $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders is undefined! WHY??
    $scope.data = [
      $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4
    ];

}]);
```

I already tried to return the $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders, but still nothing. Could it be a problem of scopes inheritance? If yes, what exactly should I do in order to solve this? If no... well, help me anyway :D

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating ammountOfFinishedOrders in an AJAX call (asynchronous) and you are trying to access it in your script prior to it being updated i.e. prior to the response received. Because of which you are not able to get the value.

So, you should move your code i.e. $scope.data inside the success callback function.

```
.success(function (data) {
       $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders = data.GetAmmountOfFinishedOrdersResult;     
       // move your code here

})
```

You can also call a function in the success callback function and do the updates in that function.

```
.success(function (data) {
           $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders = data.GetAmmountOfFinishedOrdersResult;     
           updateScope();

    })

var updateScope = function() {
    // your code here
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked! I can stop now hitting my head against the computer :D I didn't realize the asynchronous effect.
Thanks again.

Comment: @nikhil +1 for timings :)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple pal:-)

You called `GraphService` which is async service and while it return it's promise your  `console.log("value 2:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)` and `console.log("value 3:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)` already executed so definately it will be undefined.

To overcome this you can do

```
$scope.$watch(ammountOfFinishedOrders,function(newVal){
 $scope.data = [
      newVal, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4
    ];
```

});

or else put it inside your success

```
 GraphService.getAmmountOfFinishedOrders()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders = data.GetAmmountOfFinishedOrdersResult;
$scope.data = [
      $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4
    ];
            //this console.log shows me the value 3. Excellent!
            console.log("value 1:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)

            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data:' + error.message;
            });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey, thank you :) I went for the nikhil answer first and it worked. However, I am curious about the $scope.$watch method you suggested. Later I will figure out if it works in my case, because the purpose is to fill the array 'data' with values coming from de DB, i.e.:
instead of just

$scope.data = [
      $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4
    ];

I will have
$scope.data = [
      $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders,  $scope.ammountOfDelayedOrders,  $scope.ammountOfCanceledOrders
    ];

Perhaps I would have to update values with newVal1, newVal2... is it even possible?

Comment: Hey for that purpose you can look for $watchGroup here is doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope/#$watchGroup

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of asynchronous method calls. Obviously you will not get your result just below the method "dataforGraphs" method.

In a better way you can handle this by CallBack method. When GraphService method executed it will it will call "success" or "error" callback, you can call your call back method from there, like this

```
 function dataforGraphs(SuccessCallBack, FailedCallBack) {

       GraphService.getAmmountOfFinishedOrders()
            .success(function (data) {
SuccessCallBack(data.GetAmmountOfFinishedOrdersResult);

            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data:' + error.message;
FailedCallBack(error);
            });

    };

function SuccessCallBack(result){
  //do your success logic here
}

function FailedCallBack(error){
}
```

Comment: I went for the nikhil solution first and it worked. Later I will try your way. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The nature of your problem is asynchronous. `GraphService.getAmmountOfFinishedOrders()` is an asynchronous call, which means you go right to the next line of code, which is:

```
//HOWEVER... here is undefined
console.log("value 2:", $scope.ammountOfFinishedOrders)
```

Only once the promise is resolved (you get the response back from the server) that the success/error is triggered and you get inside those code blocks.

Regarding what to do, that depends on what you need to achieve. If you need to assign to a variable, then just do that. If you need to return to something, that would require a different approach.

Comment: Thank you! :) It helped me to understand the problem.